# Create alert from Kafka DLQ to Splunk

Tags: apache-kafka, splunk

Kafka code is creating log whenever it fails to process data and move to dlq (code is creating logs)

I have to generate alert when dlq error log get generated, it gives alert to splunk.

Not sure how to configure connection

Comment: We have resolved issue by creating pub/sub by routing logs and reading it on splunk

Answer (score 1):

First step would be to have [some Kafka consumer write to Splunk](https://www.splunk.com/en_us/blog/tips-and-tricks/splunk-connect-for-kafka-connecting-apache-kafka-with-splunk.html) for the topic(s) you want to ingest.

Once data is available, it might need post-processed more but then, [set up alerts](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Alert/Aboutalerts), specifically a [real-time alert](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/9.0.0/Alert/DefineRealTimeAlerts) might be best.

Alternative options would be to add Prometheus metrics into the process that produces to your DLQ, then add a simple error counter metric and hook your metrics into a different system like AlertManager or Grafana to alert on. This way, your alerting is not dependent upon Kafka consumer lag.